# Return QuerySet object (mongo) in Celery task

Tags: python, mongodb, celery, mongoengine

I have an application in which I'm using *Celery* as a task queue, a *MongoDB* database and *mongoengine* as an ORM. If I try to get an object from my database using a task and I convert it to *JSON*, it works fine. But if I try to return a *QuerySet* object it raises an error. I **NEED** to get the *QuerySet* object because I'm using it as a *LazyReferenceField* in another Model.

Is there a way to do this or get a *QuerySet* object from my task?

I've seen a solution to similar problems that suggest *Pickle*, but also discourage doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a terrible idea to try to serialize a QuerySet object but note that (Lazy)ReferenceField can be set by using the IDs so perhaps you can return simply the IDs. If that doesn't work, your best option is to return the IDs, then load the objects on the other side (the one consuming celery's output)

```
class Parent(Document):
    name = StringField()

class House(Document):
    owner = ReferenceField(Parent)

p = Parent(name='Bob').save()

House(owner=p.id).save()

h = House.objects.first()
assert h.owner.name == 'Bob'
```

Comment: Why is this a terrible idea?

Comment: A queryset object contains a pymongo Cursor so I doubt you'll be able to (de)serialize that. Now if you don't need to return a Queryset object, but need instead to return a list(Document instances), this may be possible but you may encounter issues with pickle and MongoEngine documents. Recommended way is to return JSONs serialized documents or just the IDs if possible for your use case